# VSTS 2008 Database Edition doesn't seem to know 'DATEADD' constants, any ideas?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, database-project

I'm trying to implement a database build using VSTS 2008 Database Edition. The build always fails on the following constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tablename]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_tablename_date] DEFAULT (CONVERT([varchar],dateadd(hour,(-1),getdate()),(1))) FOR [date];
```

The error that it shows is the following:

```
TSD03082: The name "hour" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
```

Anybody have an idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Do you have the latest GDR2 version?

Comment: I think so - it shows up as "Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition GDR Version 9.1.40413.00"

Comment: Is Hour an existing column name or a variable defined somewhere in the script? How about using hh instead of hour?

Comment: On a second thought, does this piece of script work using Management studio?

Comment: Yes, this script works when just executed as plain SQL in Management studio or anywhere else. Replacing 'hour' with 'hh' or any of the other constants doesn't help either, it looks like VSTSDB incorrectly assumes the thing is a column from a table and not a constant expression.

Comment: PS. Maybe I should add that that piece of SQL was actually generated by importing objects from an existing SQL 2005 database into VSTS DB. So it is definitely valid SQL ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping `hour` in square brackets, `[hour]` ?

Comment: Doesn't help unfortunately, comes back with same error:

"TSD03082: The name "[hour]" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted."

Answer (score 0):

Asked the same question on MSDN:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/24afdc7e-3cef-4322-99ff-76ac5174cf3c/

Looks like it's a bug. A workaround has been suggested in the thread.